# Change URL without removing history in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, location-href

I'm using 'ui.router' and '$state.go' to redirect page,

'navbar' of my project looks like this.

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="active">
        <a ui-sref="root.menu({brand_id:nav.brand_id})">
            <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>
            <span> {{nav.navInfo.menu.auth_name}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a ui-sref="root.picture({brand_id:nav.brand_id})">
            <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
            <span> {{nav.navInfo.picture.auth_name}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Each page show table which has list of items first.

Let us supposed a situation.

When I am in 'menu' page, I search a keyword.

Following my code, URL changes including keyword.

For example, this works like

**Before searching** :

`/menu?page=1&offset=0&limit=10`

**After searching** :

`/menu?page=1&offset=0&limit=10&searchKey=menu_name&searchString=pizza`

.

.

Then, I click 'menu' tab in 'navbar' to get entire list again.

At this time, I wanted to change URL using trigger `ui-sref` or `$(location)` or something.

When using `$(location).attr('href', url)`, changing URL successfully

but if I clicked browser back button, browser history did not maintain.

And also I've used `window.location.href`, `window.location.replace` but same result.

How can I maintain history in this case?

I'm ready for trying all ways of your suggestions!

.

.

**PS**.

If this is not enough explanation, please give me feedback.

Actually, I have no idea how to explain this more specifically. :(

And I've tried this in 'js', not 'controller'.

There was no special reason that I've done this in 'js'.

Just I thought that might be more easy way.

Thanks in advance!

.

.

**UPDATE**

I can change page by clicking each tabs on 'navbar'.

This works using `ui-sref` and perfect.

My main problem is, for example, when '.active' class is in 'menu' tab,

click 'menu' tab once again, `ui-sref` did not work.

So I used `$location`, `window` or something in 'js',

after this what I've gotten was **'removed history'**.

I want to make page in initialized status when I clicked 'menu' tab like.

**Before click tab** :

`/menu?page=1&offset=0&limit=10&searchKey=menu_name&searchString=pizza`

**After click tab** :

`/menu?page=1&offset=0&limit=10`

One more, I'm putting `?page=1&offset=0&limit=10` into URL manually,

so what I just have to do is **firing `ui-sref`** or **changing URL without removing history.**

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using Angular routers, don't use `window.location` or `$(location)` to change the page url and location. Angular router has its own mechanism of doing that, which is `$state`.

You need first to inject `$state` in your controller then you can use:

```
$state.go('yourStateHere');
```

This will keep all the tracking the history in your browser.

**Note:**

Make sure that your states are well defined in your `app.js`, I mean you need to define a respective state for the serach page taking into considertaion all the search params.

For further details you can check:

- **[ui-router Quick Reference](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference)**.
- **[StateProvider Reference](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateprovider-1)**.
- [**AngularJS Routing Using UI-Router** tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router).

Comment: Maybe you couldn't understand my question enough. T.T It's because of my weak explanation, I think. Thank you for your interest, and please see my question again. I've just updated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use angular service `$location`?
for example:

`$location.path("/main_page");`

Then you maybe need to use `$scope.$applyAsync();`

**Update** (after comments below)

```
services.service("$way", ["$location", function ($location) {
    var self = this;
    var lastBack;            //last page where you was
    this.way = new Array();
    var LIMIT_LENGTH = 30;   //limit of route history
    var curScope = null;     //current scope
    var active = true;       //is service active

    this.step = function (path, $scope) {
        curScope = $scope;
        if (lastBack != path) {
            lastBack = null;
            this.way.push(path);
            if (this.way.length > LIMIT_LENGTH) {
                this.way.shift();
            }

        }
    }

    this.goBack = function () {
        if (active) {
            var path = back();
            lastBack = path;
            if (path != "/") {
                $location.path(path);
                curScope.$applyAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    this.setActive = function (_active) {
        active = _active;
    }

    this.refresh = function () {
        this.way = new Array();
    }

    function back() {
        if (self.way.length > 1) {
            self.way.pop();
            Log.o("WAY_BACK", self.way);
            return self.way[self.way.length - 1];
        }
    }
}]);
```

Example:

```
$way.step("/blog", $scope);  //add page to path
$way.step("/main", $scope);  //add page to path
$way.goBack(); // now you on /blog page
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can I apply `$scope.$applyAsync()`? Would I add `ng-click` in `<a>` tag?

Comment: Probably you can catch it in your route function. But `ng-click` must work too. (Only thing you need to check - it may need a boolean return to approve a location change)

Comment: I can advise one more way to solve it if you have stuck with the issue: try to create your own service to control locations. I will update my answer with the example.

Comment: I saw your updated answer. This is the way to save history manually, isn't it? Are there any ways more simple than yours?